Can i install and use .pem (certificate ) file after flash esp32?
I hope everybody is fine.
PROBLEM: I focused the mqtt ssl example project been ready in esp-idf . However I can see I must add .pem file before compile and I must add target_add_binary_data command in CMake file.
However,I want to change .pem(certificate) file when i want it after device is ready to work.
Is it possible ?
If it is possible, I think that i must use file server. However , how it chose file and install without need compile again ? Can it embed .pem file through restart or any way but still if is necessary, after i add .pem file in file server in ESP32?
Can any body help me about this idea?
thanks already...
I didn't try anything yet because it shown that i need compile and flash to ESP32.

You're asking a very broad question. Certs are generally not hardcoded into the program. The ESP32 has options for storing data like NVS and file systems, so storing a certificate there makes much more sense. NVS is mature and quite convenient. How you update certificates has many answers and depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You can prepare an entire NVS partition with data on PC and flash it via the usual mechanism. You can download your certificate via HTTP, MQTT or any of the dozen network protocols Espressif supports, then overwrite the data in NVS. Depends on your needs.

Thank you for replay. So Is it possible :  if i make a web server on ESP32.  Can i take .pem file to ESP32 by chose from any directory on computer . I don't need build again for work new .pem file. Is it possible? I think it is good way that option file system because i must use file system for web server. Is not  it ?

Yes, it's possible. Web server on ESP32 does not require a file system, it's just light-weight code that accepts HTTP requests and provides you hooks to process them.

Hi Tarmo,
You assume it please:
you prepared web server on ensp32.  you connected web page on it on your explorer.  you see area to fill for .pem file. you can draged&droped or show directory for file to this area. you assume just a file enough for certificate.  Ok it must be everything it this! esp32 will use the new .pem file that you installed yet, when you restart your esp32. It dont want build project files and flash to ESP32. I want to use certificate file as automatic.
I hope I could explain my problem clear.
Can you explain shortly how can you prepare to do list ?
Thanks..

HTML, ESP32 HTTP Server, ESP32 Non-Volatile Storage Library

ok. you say i won't need build and flash again after install .pem file . Isn't it ?

Yes. It's your software. You can create it however you need it to be.

ok. i focus it. thanks.
